# Rails pg issues with offset query on production

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby

The below statement is producing issues:

```
Lang.limit(10).offset(0)
```

In my development environment rails console yields the following:

```
2.1.1 :001 > Lang.limit(10).offset(0)
  Lang Load (1.2ms)  SELECT "langs".* FROM "langs" LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
 => [#<Lang id: 1, english: "be", english_to_spanish: "ser", spanish: "una", spanish_to_english: "a", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">, #<Lang id: 2, english: "I", english_to_spanish: "Yo", spanish: "no", spanish_to_english: "do not", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">, #<Lang id: 3, english: "you", english_to_spanish: "usted", spanish: "pero", spanish_to_english: "but", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">, #<Lang id: 4, english: "with", english_to_spanish: "con", spanish: "la", spanish_to_english: "the", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">, #<Lang id: 5, english: "the", english_to_spanish: "la", spanish: "que", spanish_to_english: "that", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">, #<Lang id: 6, english: "they", english_to_spanish: "ellos", spanish: "y", spanish_to_english: "and", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">, #<Lang id: 7, english: "that", english_to_spanish: "que", spanish: "por", spanish_to_english: "by", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">, #<Lang id: 8, english: "this", english_to_spanish: "este", spanish: "lo", spanish_to_english: "it", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">, #<Lang id: 9, english: "are", english_to_spanish: "son", spanish: "se", spanish_to_english: "is", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">, #<Lang id: 10, english: "a", english_to_spanish: "un", spanish: "con", spanish_to_english: "with", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:30:35">] 
2.1.1 :002 >
```

In my production environment rails console yield the following:

```
irb(main):002:0> Lang.limit(10).offset(0)
  Lang Load (2.4ms)  SELECT "langs".* FROM "langs" LIMIT 10 OFFSET 0
=> [#<Lang id: 4172, english: "judicial", english_to_spanish: "judicial", spanish: "habitaciones", spanish_to_english: "room", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">, #<Lang id: 4173, english: "diamond", english_to_spanish: "diamante", spanish: "afortunadamente", spanish_to_english: "fortunately", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">, #<Lang id: 4174, english: "alternatives", english_to_spanish: "alternativas", spanish: "detener", spanish_to_english: "stop", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">, #<Lang id: 4175, english: "sighed", english_to_spanish: "suspirado", spanish: "antecedentes", spanish_to_english: "background", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">, #<Lang id: 4176, english: "surveys", english_to_spanish: "encuestas", spanish: "historiador", spanish_to_english: "historian", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">, #<Lang id: 4177, english: "managing", english_to_spanish: "gerente", spanish: "sobrevivir", spanish_to_english: "survive", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">, #<Lang id: 4178, english: "bottles", english_to_spanish: "botellas", spanish: "salvación", spanish_to_english: "salvation", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">, #<Lang id: 4179, english: "productive", english_to_spanish: "productivo", spanish: "renuncia", spanish_to_english: "resignation", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">, #<Lang id: 4180, english: "quarters", english_to_spanish: "cuarteles", spanish: "saliendo", spanish_to_english: "leaving", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">, #<Lang id: 4181, english: "arrangement", english_to_spanish: "disposición", spanish: "persecución", spanish_to_english: "persecution", created_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01", updated_at: "2015-01-03 20:28:01">]
irb(main):003:0>
```

As can be seen in development this produces Lang ID's 1..10 but in production it yields Lang ID's 4172..4181. Any thoughts as to why there is a difference and how I can get production environment to behave like development environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't specify a specific order in SQL, you get rows in whatever order the database wants and this is rarely the order you want. So, if you want things in a particular order, say so:

```
Lang.order(:id).offset(0).limit(10)
# ---^^^^^^^^^^
```

That will add an ORDER BY clause to the SQL and get you things in the expected order.

You're getting things in order in your development environment purely by accident, there's no guarantee that you'll get them in that order tomorrow or next week after doing some INSERTs, DELETEs, and UPDATEs.

Comment: Thanks for the added explanation too!